# PHP - ISS And invalid authentication headers

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

First off, this is my first time publishing a PHP application on a Windows Server.

Im getting this error:

---

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due a to invalid authentication headers.

Request URL: http//..../index.php

Physical Path: C....\index.php

Logon Method: Not yet determined

Logon User: Not yet determined

---

After googling for a while im even more lost than at the start.

**Should i implement some kind of headers on my PHP app, or its some magic config on the ISS or even Windows?**
(i found a few possible solutions for the second one, but honestly no clue of what am i doing)

Thanks for any pointers

**Edit: It's 7.5**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of IIS you are using, but for 7.0 check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043/) or for 7.5 [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/341978/troubleshooting-windows-authentication-problems-no-challenge-in-iis-7-5).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Anonymous Authentication is enabled and is using a User Identity with NTFS permissions for your site's filesystem. I recommend selecting the "Use Application Pool identity" option. Also ensure your Application Pool's identity is a member of the `IIS_Users` security group and similarly has the correct NTFS permissions.